# How to show results from one table joined to a second table, even if the second table doesn't have any matching records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

**Table 1**

[image: Table1]

**Table 2** has comments for the table 1, where the FK is the `ID_tb1`:

[image: Table2]

I'm trying to get a query in order to get all the comments to show as 1 table. If there is no comment in table 2 then there should be no comment but the data from table 1 should still be shown.

Here is an example of how the result should be

[image: Table result]

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Use Left join with Group_concat and Concat functions.

Comment: Hi Gordon, did try that m, but not sure why it didnt show up those without comments. If you can help me with an example it will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do [Left join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx) using Table 1 as starting table, so that all the records from Table 1 come.
- Using [Concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function, you can concatenate comment and datetime in a string.
- Using [Group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregation function, you can concat all the rows by a separator.

Try the following:

```
Select t1.id, t1.letter
       Group_concat(concat(t2.datetime, ' ', t2.comments)) as Comment 
From table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id 
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.letter
```

Comment: Maybe also a coalesce to show an empty string rather than NULL if there are no records, since it looks like they're loading the results into Excel.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn as per OP's expected output, he/she needs `NULL`

Comment: @pipechaves happy to help :) Do consider upvoting if you feel so :)